# How to modify another file in the chrome extension directory using popup.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Say I have a chrome extension directory containing manifest.json, popup.html, popup.js, logo.png, and one more file called temp.txt. If I want to rename temp.txt to hello.txt by clicking a button on popup.html, what should I do in popup.js?

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: Yeah, you can't, what would you want to modify anyway? Probably can be achieved by other means.